# The argument type 'dynamic Function(bool)?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)?' Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, casting

recently I faced this issue but I don't have any idea where is it. I am getting this error.
***The argument type 'dynamic Function(bool)?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)?'***

Where am I making mistake?

```
  class GroceryTile extends StatelessWidget {
  GroceryTile({Key? key, required this.item, required this.onComplete})
      : textDecoration = item.isComplete != null
            ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
            : TextDecoration.none,
        super(key: key);

  final GroceryItem item;
  final  Function(bool) onComplete;
  final TextDecoration textDecoration;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100.0,
      // TODO: 20 Replace this color
      color: Colors.red,
    );
  }

  

  Widget buildCheckbox() {
    return Checkbox(
      value: item.isComplete,
      onChanged: **onComplete** //error is occurring here
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if you will update your checkbox item you must use a stateful widget

Answer (score 2):

```
final void Function(bool?)? onComplete
```

Checkbox is a void function so u should also put void on you declaration for OnComplete if your not using nullsafety just remove this sign ?

Answer (score 1):

Your member onComplete is of type

```
void Function(bool)
```

It needs to be

```
void Function(bool?)
```

It must be able to deal with a null parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The error occured because checkbox **onChanged** methods needs a **Function(bool?)?** but you have supplied a **dynamic Function(bool)?**. `void Function(bool?)?` means that the value for a checkbox **onChanged** method can be a **null** or a function with a null parameter.

simple changing the signature of your **onChange** method will fix the issue.

`final void Function(bool?) onComplete;`

Better check the documentation in these kind of errors to find out the correct function signatures.

Answer (score 0):

If you typed this code from reading the book Flutter Apprentice, you may want to replace `final  Function(bool) onComplete;` with what was in the book, i.e. `final  Function(bool?)? onComplete;`

The question marks we see here are Dart's notation to allow a variable to be null. The outermost question mark `Function()? onComplete` means that the `onComplete` function may be null. The innermost question mark `Function(bool?)` means that the calling argument may be either a boolean or a null.

This null protection also exists in JavaScript and TypeScript.See this article of FreeCodeCamp: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-the-question-mark-works-in-javascript/